# p513w photo printer driver

Tags: drivers, printing

When I go thru the installation wizard I don't find a driver for the P513w on the list.  So I've been through all 7 (like 1100) that are on the list but none of them work.  Anyone got any ideas?

Tim

Answer (score 0):

I found this:  http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/19/DriverDetails?driverId=R247660&fileId=2731129060  Wonderful! An Ubuntu installer for your exact printer. However, depending on your Ubuntu version, it's too old to install correctly. Notice it was built in 2009. As an experiment, I installed it on a print server I have running 10.04. In this case, it actually pays to be old!

I copied the .ppd files and zipped them and here is a link to my Dropbox public folder: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/58267392/Dell.zip

Copy the file to your desktop. Right-click it and select Extract Here. Open a terminal and do:

```
    sudo mkdir /usr/share/ppd/Dell
    sudo cp Desktop/Dell/*  /usr/share/ppd/Dell/
```

Now add your printer and select the ppd file at /usr/share/ppd/Dell/dlP513w.ppd.

I found additional guidance here: http://ftp.dell.com/Printer/R247803_Readme.txt

Good luck and let us know your success!